# Как добавить html-теги в заголовок меню?

Tags: drupal

Как добавить html-теги в заголовок меню? Если добавить теги в меню, они конвертируются в html-коды (`&XXXX`). Нужно решение для Drupal 8. 
Для Drupal 7 есть плагины:

https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_icons

https://www.drupal.org/project/menuimage

Однако, они не подходят для Drupal 8

Я пробовал следующий код:

```
function adminimal_theme_preprocess_menu(&$vars) {
  if ($vars['menu_name'] === 'main') {
    $vars['items']['standard.front_page']['title']='<i class="icon-home"></i>';
  }
}
```

Но теги так-же конвертируются в html-коды (`&XXXX`).

Перевод вопроса:
https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/215826/how-can-i-add-html-tags-into-menu-title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужно обозначить для друпала, что ваша строка безопасна. Когда вы используете `t()` это происходит автоматически. Однако это излишне, поскольку тут нечего переводить.

В этом случае используйте аналог `t()` для строки, которая не переводится:

```
use Drupal\Core\Render\Markup;

function adminimal_theme_preprocess_menu(&$vars) {
  if ($vars['menu_name'] === 'main') {
    if (isset($vars['items']['standard.front_page'])) {
      $vars['items']['standard.front_page']['title'] = Markup::create('<i class="icon-home"></i>');
    }
  }
}
```

Перевод ответа: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/215826/how-can-i-add-html-tags-into-menu-title